# Question: Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory

I need to calculate the (distributional) Fourier transform of 
$$ f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}. $$

I unsuccessfully tried to find a differential equation for $f$ in order to solve the Fourier-transformed equation for $\hat{f}$. One may also could think of doing the integral through Residue calculus, but unfortunately the integrand doesn't converge.

Does anyone know how to do this exercise?

Answer (score 5):

Subtracting $1$ (whose Fourier transform is Dirac delta, up to a normalization constant) gives $-1/(1+x^2)$, whose Fourier transform integral *does* converge, and can be evaluated by residues: a constant multiple of $e^{-|x|}$.

Comment: the fourier transform of $1/(x+a)$ is $C e^{-bx}_{x \ge 0}$ and $2/(1+ix)(1-ix) = \frac{1}{1+ix}+\frac{1}{1-ix}$